# In IE the onbeforeunload event is fired for links that don't unload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I am writing a plugin to a CMS (umbraco) and I wish to attach a warning dialog to various actions on the page, one such action is clicking a link (JavaScript links), in most browsers the following code works well:

```
$(".propertypane").delegate("a, a div", "click", function () { window.onbeforeunload = confirmNavigateAway; });
```

The following is an issue in IE because IE appears to trigger `onbeforeunload` event when any link is clicked, even though the link is not navigating away.

I've set up an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DETTG/8/

Note: I do not have control over the ajax controls within the `propertypane`, they're written by third parties.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [page](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/10/20/onbeforeunload-event-is-fired-on-click/) will help you?

Comment: handy information, however, it won't help me because I don't control how the anchor tag is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove "href" then it will work. But then you would need to style it as a link element and add the attribute onclick if you want to execute a function. Here is the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/DETTG/34/

```
<a onclick="alert('do some ajax');" style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer">javascript</a>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a solution for me, because the html & JS is generated by third party controls. (I thought to remove the href client-side, but I'd potentially break the 3rd party functionality.)